# why clearInterval is used when we use setInterval in observables

Tags: typescript, rxjs

why do we need to return function with clearInterval when we are already unsubscribing the observable(having setInterval).Even if i dont return the function clearInterval,it gives the same result.Referring to below example
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/create.html

I tried removing the line of return and it gave the same result

```
const evenNumbers = Observable.create(function(observer) {
    let value = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (value % 2 === 0) {
            observer.next(value);
        }
    value++;
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);  ---> why is it necessary
});
const subscribe = evenNumbers.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
setTimeout(() => {
    subscribe.unsubscribe();
}, 10000);
```

in each case, result is 0 2 4 6 8

Answer (score 1):

As in the [official docs for `create`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-create) linked at the bottom of the LearnRxJs page you linked:

> onSubscription can optionally return either a function or an object with `unsubscribe` method. In both cases function or method will be called when subscription to Observable is being cancelled and should be used to clean up all resources. So, for example, if you are using `setTimeout` in your custom Observable, when someone unsubscribes, you can clear planned timeout, so that it does not fire needlessly and browser (or other environment) does not waste computing power on timing event that no one will listen to anyways.

It also defines the subscription function as the following (emphasis mine):

> A function that accepts an Observer, and invokes its `next`, `error`, and `complete` methods as appropriate, and **optionally returns some logic for cleaning up resources**.

The goal here is to give RxJs enough information to know how to clean up resources when it knows they will not be called anymore. Here, in cases that RxJs knows that the interval timer is irrelevant, it can clear the timer. You're right that *this doesn't have an immediate effect on correctness*—your function will return the same either way—but it does give you an opportunity to use memory well and keep the cleanup self-contained.

Comment: Thanku so much , it makes sense

Comment: @MehakDuaChawla Glad to help! If this solved your problem, you can click the check mark to the side of the answer to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This awards reputation points and tells the community that your question has been answered to your satisfaction. Welcome to StackOverflow and good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Under `setInterval`, the callback will continue repeating until `clearInterval` is called to stop the repetition. This is part of standard JavaScript and is handled separately from other code, such as the Observable objects you've created.